# Phone Authentication in Flutter Apllication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to apply phone Authentication in flutter application but it provide me errors, recently i have applyed sign In option with gemail and password that was working correctly.

```
I/zzb     ( 7091): ForceRecaptchaV2Flow from phoneAuthOptions = false, ForceRecaptchav2Flow from firebaseSettings = falseW/System  ( 7091): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/zzb     ( 7091): Failed to initialize reCAPTCHA config: No Recaptcha Enterprise siteKey configured for tenant/project *I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=tBXImkkf1PZ3NA1gRGiNfbyCwChtfRlMWExRZO74O1o, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846, network=null})
I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore( 7091): UID: [10154]  PID: [7091] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/System  ( 7091): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth( 7091): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid app 
info in play_integrity_token
D/FirebaseAuth( 7091): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +923225549819, error - This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 
are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]
```

I am trying to applay phone Authentication and get OTP.

Comment: "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console."